# No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python

i have already installed the required modules, refer to the image, all i want is to be able to run it on idle(python's integrated development and learning environment) as you can see on the image, i'm running powershell and when i'm on drive D: mysql.connector does not work, but going to drive C: it works, is there a way i can tell idle to import mysql.connector on drive C? actually my python is on drive D: so i'm not sure why this is happening

i also tried installing pip install mysql-connector-python and mysql-connector-python-rf, still the same problem

i'm using this code from w3schools when i run this on idle or in powershell i get the error message

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword",
  database="mydatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM customers")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a file called "mysql" on `D:/Desktop/POS System`?

Comment: ah nope, because that will instead import the mysql.py on my directory, i know that because i used to import functions.py so i can have a separate file for my functions